# Is Java MessageDigest.digest() guaranteed to return an unreferenced byte array?

Tags: java, message-digest

When I call [`MessageDigest.digest()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/MessageDigest.html#digest()) and similar methods that produce the final hash, is the resulting byte array guaranteed to be a new copy, free of other references? Or do I still need to make a defensive copy using e.g. `messageDigest.digest().clone()`?

I can't find any documentation on this. It would seem a big usability issue, not to mention a performance hit, if I need to call `clone()` every time I generate a message digest. On the other hand, if it isn't guaranteed to be free of other references, this would present a potential memory leak and security risk.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining what would keep references to them. It's most likely a local variable that gets returned and that's it, but you can always check the source. I doubt there are any explicit guarantees about it, but I'd expect the Crypto API designers to have a pretty good grip on things like this.